# Bodyparser problems with numeric nested form element names

Tags: node.js, express, connect

I have a form that looks more or less like this:

`<input type="checkbox" name="checklist[1]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checklist[2]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checklist[3]" value="1" />`

I was expecting that `request.body.checklist` looked like this (after all checkboxes were checked, of course):

`{
'1': '1',
'2': '1',
'3': '1'
}`

But what I got was a array, without the indexes I need to associate the result:

`['1', '1', '1']`

This seems like a bug to me. If I prepend the indexes with some string (like `id-`), I get the object but... Is there a workaround so I don't need to change this to every form element and also every controller?

Answer (score 0):

1) You can write middleware that will do it for all your controllers

2) You can stop using `express.bodyParser` and parse data via middleware by yourself like this

```
app.use (function(req, res, next) {
    var data='';
    req.setEncoding('utf8');
    req.on('data', function(chunk) { 
       data += chunk;
    });

    req.on('end', function() {
        req.body = data;
        next();
    });
});
```

in this way you will get data formed as you want